# How can I show appendices as "APÊNDICE A – Title of the appendix" in TOC using the package `appendix`?

Tags: appendices, appendix

Currently, I have `Apêndice A Title of the appendix` in my Table of Contents (see link below), but I need `APÊNDICE A – Title of the appendix` (note the capital letters APÊNDICE and the "en dash" before the title.

This change must affect only the ToC. The title on the appendix page itself is fine as it is now.

I guess this is an easy task, but I haven't succeeded.

https://www.overleaf.com/read/qdstcnhswnwc

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[greek,portuguese,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Introduction}
Bla bla
\cleardoublepage

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Title of the appendix}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Title of another appendix}
\cleardoublepage
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy the ABNT style?

Comment: @Joseph, I have to adapt a book to the norms of ABNT. I have already tried simply to replace the class `book` with `abntex`, but some packages I use didn't work in that class.

Comment: The class is called `abntex2`, not `abntex`. You'll have plenty more problems trying to do it all from scratch. Better ask people here or elsewhere why those packages don't work with `abntex2` -- have you tried that? By the way, who on earth has to adapt a **book** (_not_ a thesis) to `ABNT` rules? Which publisher prints a book **only** according to `ABNT` _and_ accepts LaTeX? This may seem picky, but changing your approach might save you lots of time.

Comment: Yes, it was `abntex2` what I tried. It's a university publisher which really requires `ABNT` for books too. They usually required the book text as a Microsoft Word file (for they to pass it to InDesign), but they accepted PDF files from LaTeX users as long as the authors adapt their books to the rules themselves.

Comment: Traditionally, this publisher focused on humanities books, but now they are starting publishing natural science books too. Many science authors submitted their books as PDF files and only revealed that they didn't have a `DOC` file after having the books accepted.

Comment: I have already used a pdf-to-word converter and send them the  `DOC` file, but it ended up being so large that even scrolling down its pages was too slow.

Comment: Anyway, I think I have finished the adaptation right now.

Comment: By the way, although I didn't use the `abntex2` class, I used the `abntex2cite` package for the references.

Comment: Since you didn't tell us why `abntex2` did not work (and I think you haven't tried the `abnt` package either), and since you said you're done adapting your output to the publisher's standards, I guess the time-saving shortcuts go out of the window. Good luck, then.

Comment: When replacing `book` with `abntex2`, there were a lot of `option clash` messages, for packages `babel`, `appendix`, `hyperref`, etc., and also lots of `undefined control sequence` messages, such as `\singlespacing` and `\cftfignumwidth`.

Maybe I could just use `abntex2` without all these packages and commands, but I didn't anticipate how difficult it was to adapt the `book` class to ABNT. I started like "I just have to change this and this" and the publisher gradually added more requirements: "you have to change this too... and this, and this and that...".

Comment: When I have time I'll submit a template of my ABNT-adapted book to the Overleaf Gallery so that people can show me how to have the same result with `abntex2`.

Comment: Option clashes occur because the packages were already loaded."Maybe I could just use abntex2 without all these packages and commands" -- you're right: you *don't* need those packages, as they're provided by the `abntex2`class. You don't need to fiddle with line spacing either (unless you want something different from ABNT): the class follows strictly the ABNT rules. And remember: what your publisher wants/expects/thinks ABNT is **may not be ABNT**. The only thing left is chapter/section head styles, which can be easily changed within `abntex2` or `memoir`.

Comment: About submitting a template, I'd advise you rather to post specific questions here at tex.stackexchange, instead of asking for a grand proof-reading, code-enhancing, project-refurbishing free-consulting-cum-lesson enterprise for something whose desired results you have already hopefully achieved (unless the code is really stripped down to comparing two sparse MWE's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your question can be answered by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410955/182785).

For renaming, you'll need to add this:

```
\renewcommand\appendixname{APÊNDICE}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{APÊNDICE}
```

Comment: My appendices are defined as chapters (as I have `book` instead of `article`). What's the equivalent to `\@seccntformat` for chapters?

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question to complement @Vinccool96's answer.

The answer of @Vinccool96 didn't completely apply to my MWE because its class is `book` instead of `article`. However, it helped me find the solution that worked in my case.

Based on the explanation in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384048/91816, I added the following code immediately below `\begin{appendices}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\thechapter\space\textendash\space\ #1}% <-- modification
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi}
\makeatother
```